# Parse params with multiple types from url/path to object type in typescript

Tags: typescript

This currently can only parse something like `/user/:id/update/:id2` and always will be string.

```
type Data = "/user/:id/update/:id2" // -> { id: string, id2: string }

type Parse<T extends string, Memo extends string[] = []> =
  T extends `${infer Part}/${infer Others}`
  ? Part extends `:${infer Value}` ? Parse<Others, [...Memo, Value]> : Parse<Others, Memo>
  : T extends `:${infer Value}` ? [...Memo, Value] : Memo;

type TupleToObject<T extends string[]> = {
  [Key in T[number]]: string
}

// { id: string, id2: string }
type Result = TupleToObject<Parse<Data>>
```

Is it possible to parse sometime like `"/user/:id(string)/update/:id2(number)/:id3"`? It defaults to string if it's not specified. This will be:

```
{
  id: string;
  id2: number;
  id3: string;
}
```

Also is it possible to make the code simpler.

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAIghsOUC8UBEB6ArgZwgJwwC4BLAE2zDIQmPICY0oMMoBaAPigG8pyioOYPhIA7AOYAaPmXoChIiVAC+AWABQG0JCgAFOPjwAeACpQIAD2ARRZHIOFipUALIQAtgHtzVm3YeK4gDaALooUKFcyBpQUGaW1rb2AAYAJNxiAGYEegbAyhjpWTkA8sAAFgQ4yskxUAD8ufjAPon+yURFotn4UABqcAA2WBA1DU3GZZWG0kEAdAtuXtIDwxAhXAL6hhBGU1XSS54cdQLxvklQHV09-UMjY43zix6eK-frUAJHANwaWuBoCYsGBBhATJ4SgAjABWEAAxsBTK0-PYFE5IuFuHUggBpCAgPiiOJBURYdxQgghELyRwSDRqTTqFg8GS0wLSBjspwqAE6ABKEBwWEGLVQwNB4MhsIRSO2xngiA4HCAA)

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/Wvo9Mw) meet your needs?  If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Yes. It's right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you'll need some kind of mapping from type *names* like `"string"` and `"number"` in your url to their corresponding *types*:

```
interface TypeMap {
  string: string,
  number: number,
  // add other types here
}
```

Then we can write `KV<T>` which takes a string like `"foo(bar)"` and turns it into a type like `{foo: TypeMap["bar"]}`, and takes a string like `"foo"` (without the parenthesized type name) and turns it into a type like `{foo: string}`:

```
type KV<T extends string> = T extends `${infer U}(${infer V})` ?
  Record<U, V extends keyof TypeMap ? TypeMap[V] : any> : Record<T, string>
```

That should hopefully be self-explanatory; we check if the input `T` is a string `U` followed by a string `V` in parentheses.  If so, we look up `V` in `TypeName` (and if it's not found we default to `any`. You might want to do something else, but it's not specified in the question and thus out scope here). The type `Record<U, TypeMap[V]>` using [the `Record` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type) is that.  Otherwise we produce `Record<T, string>`.

---

Now we can write `Parse` similar to how you had it, a [tail-recursive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-5.html#tail-recursion-elimination-on-conditional-types) where you extract all text after a colon (`:`) and up until the next slash (`/`). This becomes the input to `KV`, and we accumulate the output in `A` via [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) (there doesn't seem to be a reason to keep track of the *order* of the identifiers, so we don't need [tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types)):

```
type Parse<T extends string, A = unknown> =
  T extends `${string}:${infer F}/${infer R}` ? Parse<R, A & KV<F>> :
  (A & (T extends `${string}:${infer F}` ? KV<F> : unknown)) extends
  infer U ? { [K in keyof U]: U[K] } : never
```

There's a little wrinkle there when we hit the last colon because there might not be a slash at the very end. So we have to remember to maybe intersect one more piece, which is where `T extends` ${string}:${infer F} `? KV<F> : unknown` comes from.

---

Let's test it out:

```
type Data = "/user/:id(string)/update/:id2(number)/:id3"
type ParsedData = Parse<Data>    
/* type ParsedData = {
    id: string;
    id2: number;
    id3: string;
} */
```

Looks good, the output is as expected.  Of course such recursive types can sometimes have bizarre edge case behavior, so it's always a good idea to test thoroughly against expected use cases and be prepared to refactor.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKAlgdgLgpgTgMwIYGMYAIAqBPADjAWSV3QG9R10BnKOSAcwC5raGAaC9CAVwFsAjeMx4D4HEJQD0k9AHsoAC3jooeGFVABfUKFX50AaQBqAHkzoYAD1gQAJlRZ0I9AHzoAvFgvWYdhwAMAElJIBGUAVU0ACmDQ5SNNAEp-dAB+TgAlGBRZOFsTcLZ0I28be3QAaxhsWQQsNSISVPr8RoBtIwBddGYkCGw3ZiycvLMimidXHRA9DAAFJDgqGDNS33KJ9nQAQQ90bggKiFkAdwg3d05zKzKA4M3nTUZYiDC4dAAxTUkXt-QMzQpZoLJYrDJFXYAMkMpg+LkGnCiUPQUWuPj86CCpAe9Cev2UXyBMJMcJ6+0OxzOiUSaz8nDi73CaTI6DaBnQkEq1Vq6HCnWY4TZ3U0ZIgMAAbvBprN0AARJBQJB7ABEkm4yzgkkYYFsURxiTVuFsCpgWp1ACYoiJBHADdrbABmZW6NToEHLWzyxV7d0rL1IFzTSQAKhUrt9noVSs85AklA5tmYOIA3JxKBbhHwbam4+nHUnWM4cyLg5IgA)